# I keep getting an error message with this code, does anyone know why?

Tags: python

```py
def show_total_rooms_and_rates(dictionary):
    print('All the rooms and the rate you just checked')
    for k,v in dictionary.items():
        print(k.ljust(30,'.')+v.rjust(10))
```

I keep getting this error message:

```sh
'int' object has no attribute 'rjust'
```

... for the last line

Comment: Because you're trying to call `ljust` on an int.

Comment: Try: `str(v).rjust(10)`

Comment: While the answers are correct about the why and how to fix it, you also have the option of string formatting, i.e., `print(f'{k:.<30}{v:10}')`

Answer (score 0):

I think It is because you are trying to rjust an int variable.

Add str() around the things you are trying to rjust:

```py
def show_total_rooms_and_rates(dictionary):
  print('All the rooms and the rate you just checked')
  for k,v in dictionary.items():
    print(str(k).ljust(30,'.')+str(v).rjust(10))
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the variable "v" is an integer.
You can cast "v" to a string, example

```
print(str(k).ljust(30,'.') + str(v).rjust(10))
```

This will ensure that no matter if either k or v is an int, it will always be converted to a string and print as normal.